# How can i set a global variable's name by prompt?

Tags: parameters, compiler-errors, global-variables, common-lisp

In order to define a class (*for a school project that implements classes and object*), I have to give them a name from prompt when i create the class with the method `def-class class-name parents ...`.

Prompt should reply me with `CLASS-NAME` to tell me that the class has been saved as a global variable (*class are a list of parameters*).

So in the code i think i should write something like that:

```
(defun def-class (class-name parents slot-value) 
    (defparameter X (list '(class-name parents slot-value))))
```

where X must be `CLASS-NAME`.
But if I try to write that name of variable gives me literally the word I wrote in the code, like it doesn't recognise that X is a variable and it should evaluate that to take the value.

Comment: Hi! I have trouble understanding what you have to implement. Can you please write an example of how you would define a class, hypothetically? For example, my understanding is that you would write "(def-class foo ())" in the REPL (read-eval-print-loop), i.e. the toplevel, and the return value that would be printed would be the symbol "FOO" . Please edit your question with this information if possible. `defparameter` inside defun is discouraged. Also, the quote around `(class-name parents slot-value)` make it a non-evaluated list, i.e. it will evaluate as the list of *symbols* `class-name`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you want to do. But a few remarks:

- `defparameter` is usually a top-level form to define a global variable. It's typically not used inside functions. To set a variable use `setf` or `setq`.
- variables introduced by `defvar` and `defparameter` should be written as `*var*` and not `var`. This makes sure that they cannot clash with lexical variables.
- quoted data will not be evaluated. If you want to create a list based on computed values (like values of variables) use for example the function `list`.

Code:

```
(defun def-class (class-name parents slot-value) 
  (setf *x* (list (list class-name parents slot-value))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defclass myclass ()                                                 
  ((slot-1 :initarg :slot-1 :accessor slot-1)
   (slot-2 :initarg :slot-2 :accessor slot-2)))
;;#<STANDARD-CLASS MYCLASS>

(defparameter mc (make-instance 'myclass :slot-1 'a :slot-2 'b))
;; MC
(slot-1 mc)
;; A
(slot-2 mc)
;; B
```